# How to highlight multiple values using angular filter?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Once i have search results rendered i am highlighting search keywords , so in case of multiple keyowrds search filter is not highlighting all keywords only last search keyword is being highlighted, how can i highlight all search keywords using below filter ?

filter.js

```
  angular.module('loggingApp').filter('trusted', function($sce) {
      return function(text, phrase) {
        if (phrase) {
          var data = text.replace(/[|&;$%@"<>()+,]/g, "");
          data = data.replace(new RegExp('(' + phrase + ')', 'gi'),
            '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>');
          return $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
        }

        text = text.replace(/[|&;$%@"<>()+,]/g, "");
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
      };
    });
```

modalCtrl.js

```
// e.g var data.searchStr = ["standard","industry"];

angular.forEach(data.searchStr,function(item) {
           $scope.searchStr = item;
        });;
        $scope.showMessages = data.messageObj;
```

main.html

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in showMessages | filter:searchStr" >
                    <td >{{item.filename}}</td>
                    <td class="serverResults"  ng-bind-html="item.value | trusted:searchStr">{{item.value}}</td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: Can you provide a plunker?

Comment: What is the value of `data.messageObj`?

Comment: @Mr_Perfect sorry dont access to plunker `data.messageObj` is a response from server that contains keywords search

Comment: Does `item.value` will be like `some text (search_string) few data (search_string)` this?

Comment: `var showMessages = [{filename:"server20170609133555.log" ,value:"336a286c-50e7-49c7-85b7-fdb0e218d914 {"event":{"body":{"outageStarted":0,"lastTimeAccessProviderContacted"}];` so here item.value will display the results and highlight keyword `searchStr`

Comment: Not clear. Better to have a plunker. But one thing is sure that something is going wrokg at this line `data = data.replace(new RegExp('(' + phrase + ')', 'gi'),
            '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>');`. Replace correctly then you may not face the problem